# Loop going on longer than intended checking for empty line

Tags: c, string, while-loop, scanf

I have a loop that is stopped once a flag is set to 1.

```
scanf("%d", &next);
scanf("%d", &next1);
int done=0,next,next1;
while (done==0) {
            printf("%d,%d.",next,next1);
            if (getchar()=='\n') {
                scanf("%d", &next);
                scanf("%d", &next1);
            }
            //if not, set flag and stop looping
            else{
                done=1;
            }
}
```

It scans for 2 numbers from every line of input every loop until there are no more lines of the input left. I thought this would work fine but I encountered a problem when I tested out the following input:

```
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
```

The output should be

```
1,0.
1,1.
1,2.
1,3.
```

but instead it prints the last loop twice like this:

```
1,0.
1,1.
1,2.
1,3.
1,3.
```

Why does this scan the last line twice before terminating? is there a character I can check for so it ends after it prints the first "1,3."?

Comment: Why have you declared `next` and `next1` _after_ using them in `scanf()`? Suggest posting actual code would be more helpful.

Comment: You need to test the scanf calls for EOF.  After reading the newline that’s the last character in the file, you have two scanf calls that fail, hut you loop back and print the previous values again.

Comment: How do I test a scanf call? when I call scanf doesn't it already scan the value? so I don't really understand how I'm supposed to test scanf and assign my next and next1 values too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf()` -

> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.

So, when the no more lines of the input left, the `scanf()` returns `EOF` and the `while` loop iterate because `done` is not set to `1` yet and `printf()` prints the value stored in `next` and `next1` one more time. That's why the last entered value printed twice. After this the condition `if (getchar()=='\n')` fails and `done` set to `1` and `while` loop exits.

You can do:

```
int done=0,next,next1;
while (done==0) {
    if (scanf("%d%d", &next, &next1) != EOF)
        printf("%d,%d.",next,next1);
    else
        done=1;
}
```

Or

```
while (scanf("%d%d", &next, &next1) != EOF)
    printf("%d,%d.",next,next1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like that

```
int main(){
    int next,next1;
    scanf("%d", &next);
    scanf("%d", &next1);
    while (getchar()=='\n') {
        printf("%d,%d.\n",next,next1);
        scanf("%d", &next);
        scanf("%d", &next1);
    }
}
```

by this way you save a little bit of memory, and is more readable. The output should be correct now, try by yourself.